# Why my Oracle sql query is not using the available indexes on join columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I have executed the below query but the indexes are not being used.

Following are the indexes available for the below tables.
I have provided the explain plan generated for the query.
Can some one please tell me why the indexes are not being used.
I have gathered the table statistics multiple times also.

```
wms_area_master - Index name: WMS_AREA_MASTER_PK - Index columns: DC_CODE, DC_AREA
wms_bin_master - WMS_BIN_MASTER_IDX - DC_CODE, DC_AREA

EXPLAIN PLAN FOR 
SELECT *
from wms_area_master wam ,
wms_bin_master wbm       
where WAM.DC_CODE = wBM.DC_CODE
and WAM.DC_AREA = wBM.DC_AREA; 

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 2387754896
 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |                 | 41079 |    12M|   252   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN         |                 | 41079 |    12M|   252   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| WMS_AREA_MASTER |   217 | 32984 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| WMS_BIN_MASTER  | 41058 |  6214K|   248   (2)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - access("WAM"."DC_CODE"="WBM"."DC_CODE" AND 
              "WAM"."DC_AREA"="WBM"."DC_AREA")
 
Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
   - this is an adaptive plan
   - 1 Sql Plan Directive used for this statement
```

Thanks

Comment: If your index is not being used it's either because it isn't any use, or stats are out of date, or you've done something  non-sargable. For a 217 and 41,079 row table's it's quicker to just scan than use an index. Do you have a performance issue?

Comment: The "dynamic sampling (level=2)" implies that at least one of the tables does not have any optimizer statistics. Although I think Justin is right, and that statistics aren't the main problem here, they may become a problem in the future. You might want to ensure that your default autostats jobs are running correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Your query doesn't appear to have any predicates, just join conditions, so there doesn't appear to be any reason to use an index here.  Since you need to read all the data from both tables, the fastest way to do so will be to do table scans.  Using an index isn't necessarily faster and doing a table scan isn't necessarily slower-- it depends on how much of the data you need to access.

If you had predicates in your query that restricted the rows that were returned, Oracle might find it advantageous to use an index on those columns.  If your projection (the columns in the `select`) list were only columns that were part of an index rather than every column in the table, it is possible that Oracle would choose to do a full scan of the index rather than of the table assuming the index segment was meaningfully smaller than the table segment.